# How to create nested document in Solr indexing?

Tags: java, solr, indexing, document, solrj

I want to create nested document in solr, I am using java/GWT/SolrJ.

Currently I am indexing following fields:

Items:
id   title     desc.

1     xyz    xyzxyzxyz

2     pqr     pqrpqrpqr

3     abc     abcabcabc.

But now i want to create one more document linked with each document from above i.e. for id 1 there is one subdocument which contains follwing fields:

Item_User_Details:

for item 1 :

user details

1         qweqweqwe

2         xyzxyzxyz

3         asdasdasd

in this way I want to create for each item id from above table, there is one linked document of item_user_details.

How can I do this...?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our schema we've a lot of related tables.

We decided to flatten all relations into one document. To achieve this we created a custom importer (using SolrJ), which loads each document from the index, adds the related fields and write that document back.

[edit]
We do this in the following way:

1. export the data in a csv-file for each table (item, item_user_details)
2. import each csv-file into Solr, starting with the top (item in your case)
3. Start an Embedded-Solr server:
   `System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", config.getSolrIndexPath());`
   `CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();`
   `this.coreContainer = initializer.initialize();`
   `this.solr = new EmbeddedSolrServer(this.coreContainer, "");`
   Alternatively you can access a remote solr instance:
   `this.solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://[your-url]/solr");`
4. Create a SolrDocument for each line in the file
5. add it to the index `this.solr.add(ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument(doc));`
6. Commit `this.solr.commit();`
7. Load documents from the index (items)
8. Idetify relations in the csv-file for item_user_details via the document id (item-id)
9. Exted the loaded document with the fields from item_user_details
10. Commit the Document again

Comment: Rene: can you please give me the example or link to refer...because I am new to Solr so do not have enough idea.

Comment: Rene: That means all the data i.e. item and user_item_data is indexed in same flat document..??
What then If I want to create another document for item_user_details..?

Comment: Yes yo'll have one big denormalized document.

Whats the use case for indexin item_user_details in a different document?